# Operational Error on MySQL AWS RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws, sqlalchemy

The heading pretty much describes it all, here are some more information on the Amazon RDS I am using.

- Engine: MySQL Community 8.0.28
- Class db.r6g.large
- Multi-AZ no. The data volume is very small, not even a few megs, as I am just doing some PoC to test the connectivity.
- Latency from MySQL commandline: 10ms
- Availability zone: ap-southeast-1
- Set up the inbound traffic rule for port 3306 of the relevant security group.

These are the client details

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Python 3.10
- SQL Alchemy 1.4.44
- mysql Ver 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
- Geographic location: Singapore

Here is a sample code snippet (hopefully, self-explanatory)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8
uri:str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://della:random_password@tensorflow-dump.apj-xjge.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/convnet'
with create_engine(url=uri).connect() as out_client: # This line throws error
    logging.info(msg=f'Connected to {uri}.')        
    results.to_sql(name='machine_name', con=out_client,
                                            if_exists='append', index=False)
    logging.info(msg=f'Pushed data.')
```

So, I am encountering the operational error on a sporadic basis, once every 3-4 attempts of running the above code. It is not reproducible, but makes the database unsuitable for production usage. When I do get the error, the flow waits for about 12 minutes at the `create_engine` command before throwing the error.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/della/supply-chain-dev/clustering_results_postprocess/src/push.py", line 119, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main=main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/della/supply-chain-dev/clustering_results_postprocess/src/push.py", line 111, in main
    with create_engine(url=out_dbase_uri).connect() as out_client:
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 210, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 325, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 888, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 491, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 210, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 271, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 684, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 210, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 680, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 293, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1178, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 293, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 104
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

So I am not sure if it is a

- resource issue (need a machine with more RAM, or more powerful database instance)
- something to do with credentials, connection string, port firewall etc. (in that case, the code would fail with a guarantee)
- merely the internet connection at my work is not reliable (there is no other obvious sign of the connection being snappy, the usual apps, browsing etc. work very well).

When I try with `mysql>` command line, the connectivity works very well consistently.

Comment: Just checking, are you using replication at all?

Comment: @dbdemon I am not, is it something enabled by default, or should I enable it explicitly? Any how-to documentation?

Comment: I was just thinking that if replication *is* enabled, then it could explain the intermittent nature of the error. With replication there would presumably be some kind of load-balancer that would forward connections to different replicas. If one of the replicas is faulty but the load-balancer still forwards connections to it, then in some cases you will get a working connection and other times you will get an error.

Comment: @dbdemon thanks, it certainly is a possibility. In that case, it is entirely Amazon's internal issue, and basically I cannot do anything?

Comment: This looks like a routing issue where there is no route back from the database server over the load balancer(s) to the client host.

Comment: @theamoeba so if I want to really correct the error, who do I approach? My company's network administrator? Or some kind of AWS support? My network administrator will never look into any application level debugging, he will at most ensure the laptop has internet connection, that is it. Is there a way to prove to him it really is a networking issue?

Comment: @Della could be a firewall issue maybe? You mention that this is on RDS you might wanna check your security groups.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of the code you gave in the post, you did not set the `connect_time` or the `pool_recycle` value for the [create_engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) command.

Please note that the mysql command line is a different client-side platform. There are the variables [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) and [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), which are usually set very high by defaults (28800 (which is in seconds), is also 8 hours). So you would not get a session time out so intermittently.

## RECOMMENDATION

You should login to the RDS Instance and run this

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.interactive_timeout,@@global.wait_timeout;
```

Then, set your `pool_recycle` to whichever value is smaller.

Comment: Hey @Della, please have a look at this answer !!!

Comment: FWIW, I don't bother with `interactive_timeout` because the only client that uses this is the mysql CLI.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a networking/routing issue because of the system error 104.

Comment: Is the numbering scheme following the same system as HTTP error codes, as in 200 means success, 404 means resource missing etc.?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).